# Помогите переписать код через pdo

Tags: php, pdo

У меня есть БД - store. Таблица: mail (id,mail).
Помогите переписать php через PDO,а не mysqli

mail.php

```html
<script src="../js/mail.js"></script>
<div class="mail">
 <h1>Подписка на новости</h1>
 <p>Без лишних слов - мы действительно лучшие </p>
 <div style="border: 1px solid #000;width: 300px; margin: 2rem auto;text-align: center;"></div>
 <form class="mail-input" action="../php/savemail.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" required name="mail" placeholder="Ваш e-mail" maxlength="35" id="savemail">
  <input type="button" onclick="Post()" name="" value="Подписаться">
 </form>
</div>
```

```js
function Post() // Наша функция, которая будет осуществлять ajax-отправку
{
 var pmail = document.getElementById('savemail').value;
 var obj = {
  mail: pmail
 };
       jQuery.ajax({    // Начала конструкции для работы с Ajax через jQuery
                type: "POST", // Метод, которым получаем данные из формы
                url: "../php/savemail.php", // Обработчик формы. 
                data: obj, // Этот метод, берет форму с id=form и достает оттуда данные
                success: function(html) {   // функция выполняемая при успешном отправлении данных
                    //location.reload(true);
                    alert(html);
                }
        });
}
```

savemail.php

```html
<?php
include_once('bd.php');

if (isset($_POST['mail'])){
  
  $mail = $_POST['mail'];
  $mail = htmlspecialchars($mail);
    $mail = stripslashes($mail);
   

   $resultins = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO mail(mail) VALUES ('$mail')");
   if ($resultins == TRUE){
     echo "Вы оставили Заявку";
   } else{
     echo "Что то пошло не так попробуйте позже 1";
   }
}
else{
  echo "Что то пошло не так попробуйте позже 2";
  echo $_POST['mail'];
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Уважаемый Олег, на будущее учтите что данное сообщество не предлагает готовые решения, а только помогает по сути верными советами, и способами решения задач.

```
<?php

define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'namedb');
define('DB_USER', 'userdb');
define('DB_PASS', '12345');
define('DB_CHAR', 'utf8');

class DB
{
    protected static $instance = null;

    final private function __construct() {}
    final private function __clone() {}

    public static function instance()
    {
        if (self::$instance === null)
        {
            $opt  = array(
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => FALSE,
                PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS    => array('myPDOStatement'),
            );
            $dsn = 'mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME.';charset='.DB_CHAR;
            self::$instance = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $opt);
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
    public static function __callStatic($method, $args) {
        return call_user_func_array(array(self::instance(), $method), $args);
    }
}

class myPDOStatement extends PDOStatement
{
    function execute($data = array())
    {
        parent::execute($data);
        return $this;
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['mail'])){

  $mail = $_POST['mail'];
  $mail = htmlspecialchars($mail);
  $mail = stripslashes($mail);

$sql="INSERT INTO `mail` (`mail`) VALUES (?)";
$resultins = DB::prepare($sql) ->execute([$mail]);

   if ($resultins == TRUE){
     echo "Вы оставили Заявку";
   } else{
     echo "Что то пошло не так попробуйте позже 1";
   }
}
else{
  echo "Что то пошло не так попробуйте позже 2";
  echo $_POST['mail'];
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!